# How is a 3-d tensor indexed by two 2d tensors?

Tags: python, arrays, indexing, pytorch, tensor

Here's a snapshot from line 15-20 in [DIM](https://github.com/rdevon/DIM/blob/master/DIM.py)

```
def random_permute(X):
    X = X.transpose(1, 2)
    b = torch.rand((X.size(0), X.size(1))).cuda()
    idx = b.sort(0)[1]
    adx = torch.range(0, X.size(1) - 1).long()
    X = X[idx, adx[None, :]].transpose(1, 2)

    return X
```

where `X` is a tensor of size [64, 64, 128], `idx` a tensor of size [64, 64], `adx`  a tensor of size [64].
How does `X = X[idx, adx[None, :]]` work? How can we use two 2d tensors to index a 3d tensor? What really happens to `X` after this indexing?

Comment: What are the dimensions of `X`?

Comment: @Alex The shape of `X` is [64, 64, 128]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things will be more clear if we consider a smaller concrete example. Let

```
x = np.arange(8).reshape(2, 2, 2)
b = np.random.rand(2, 2)
idx = b.argsort(0) # e.g. idx=[[1, 1], [0, 0]]
adx = np.arange(2)[None, :] # [[0, 1]]
y = x[idx, adx] # implicitly expanding 'adx' to [[0, 1], [0, 1]]
```

In this example, we'll have `y` as

```
y[0, 0] = x[idx[0, 0], adx[0, 0]]=x[1, 0]
y[0, 1] = x[idx[0, 1], adx[0, 1]]=x[1, 1]
y[1, 0] = x[idx[1, 0], adx[1, 0]]=x[0, 0]
...
```

It may be helpful to see how we do the same in tensorflow:

```
d0, d1, d2 = x.shape.as_list()
b = np.random.rand(d0, d1)
idx = np.argsort(b, 0)
idx = idx.reshape(-1)
adx = np.arange(0, d1)
adx = np.tile(adx, d0)

y = tf.reshape(tf.gather_nd(x, zip(idx, adx)), (d0, d1, d2))
```

Answer (score 0):

From my guess `X` must be a 3D tensor, since it usually represents a batch of training data.

As far as the functionality of this function is concerned, it randomly *permutes* the input data tensor `X` and it does this using the following steps:

- First it initializes the tensor `b` with values sampled from uniform distribution.
- Next this tensor is sorted along dimension 0 and the sorting indices are pulled out to tensor `idx`.
- The tensor `adx` is just an integer tensor of values ranging from 0 to 63.

Now, the below line is where all the magic happens:

```
X[idx, adx[None, :]].transpose(1, 2)
```

We use the indices we got before `idx` and `adx` (`adx[None, :]` is simply a row vector of two dimension). Once we have that, we transpose the axes 1 and 2 exactly like what we did at the beginning of the function in the line:

```
X = X.transpose(1, 2)
```

---

Here is a contrived example, for better understanding:

```
# our input tensor
In [51]: X = torch.rand(64, 64, 32)

In [52]: X = X.transpose(1, 2)

In [53]: X.shape
Out[53]: torch.Size([64, 32, 64])

In [54]: b = torch.rand((X.size(0), X.size(1)))

# sort `b` which returns a tuple and take only indices
In [55]: idx = b.sort(0)[1]

In [56]: idx.shape
Out[56]: torch.Size([64, 32])

In [57]: adx = torch.arange(0, X.size(1)).long()

In [58]: adx.shape
Out[58]: torch.Size([32])

In [59]: X[idx, adx[None, :]].transpose(1, 2).shape
Out[59]: torch.Size([64, 64, 32])
```

The important thing to note here is how we got the same shape in the last step as the shape of the input tensor which is `(64, 64, 32)`.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Could you please explain "We use the indices we got before idx and adx (adx[None, :] is simply a row vector of two dimension)." in more detail? I could not follow it. How can we use two two-dimension tensors to index a three-dimension tensor? What really happens to `X` after this indexing?

Comment: That's the way slicing works. Using 1D tensors as slicing indices would only return a 2D tensor. So, we use 2D tensors because we want the result as a 3D tensor.

Comment: I'm not so sure what did you mean. But I tried to output the shape of `X[idx]`, where `X` and `idx` are defined the same as the code you showed above. It has size `[64, 32, 32, 64]`. Could you please tell me why `X[idx]` is a 4d tensor?